# {d3.js} migration v3 to v4: code work on v3 (d3.layout.stack()) error v4 (d3.stack())

Tags: d3.js, migration

I'm trying to migrate D3 from v3 to v4:

Read:
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#shapes-d3-shape

See:
`d3.layout.stack` ↦ `d3.stack`

I changed my working code:

Code working on v3: `(d3.layout.stack())`

Code producing error in v4: `(d3.stack())`

V4:

```
var dvstack = d3.stack(); 
var layers = dvstack(d3.range(nLocal).map(function(d,i) { ...
console.log(dvstack);

function stack(data) {

 var kz = keys.apply(this, arguments),
     i,
     m = data.length,
     n = kz.length,
     sz = new Array(n),
     oz;

 for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   for (var ki = kz[i], si = sz[i] = new Array(m), j = 0, sij; j < m;++j) {
     si[j] = sij = [0, +value(data[j], ki, j, data)];
     sij.data = data[j];
   }
   si.key = ki;
 }

 for (i = 0, oz = order(sz); i < n; ++i) {
   sz[oz[i]].index = i;
 }

 offset(sz, oz);
 return sz;    }

layers[c].dvnum = c;
```

> Error: 
>   SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'dvnum' of undefined or null reference

V3:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack(); 
var layers = stack(d3.range(nLocal).map(function(d,i) { ...
console.log(stack);

function stack(data, index) {

 if (!(n = data.length)) return data;
 var series = data.map(function(d, i) {
   return values.call(stack, d, i);
 });
 var points = series.map(function(d) {
   return d.map(function(v, i) {
     return [ x.call(stack, v, i), y.call(stack, v, i) ];
   });
 });
 var orders = order.call(stack, points, index);
 series = d3.permute(series, orders);
 points = d3.permute(points, orders);
 var offsets = offset.call(stack, points, index);
 var m = series[0].length, n, i, j, o;
 for (j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
   out.call(stack, series[0][j], o = offsets[j], points[0][j][1]);
   for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
     out.call(stack, series[i][j], o += points[i - 1][j][1], points[i][j][1]);
   }
 }
 return data;    }

layers[c].dvnum = c;
```

Screenshot of the working code in v3:
[image: screenshot working code (D3 v3)]

Screenshot of the working code (D3 v3) console.log(layers)
[image: screenshot console.log(layers) working code (D3 v3)]

Screenshot of the (D3 v4) console.log(layers)
[image: screenshot console.log(layers) (D3 v4)]

Comment: v3 version
https://jsfiddle.net/9y2g65qc/

Comment: prompt that I miss in attempt to translate this code in v4

Comment: I'm also having the same problem...

Comment: draft  (code working v4) https://jsfiddle.net/9y2g65qc/13/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134687/d3-js-stack-layout-upgrading-from-v3-to-v4/39221430#39221430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, it's actually quite easy.

You simply want to ***transpose*** your matrix so that it's looks like somethings which is close to the array of objects the new stack function is waiting for:

```
var n = 4, // number of layers
m = 58, // number of samples per layer
stack = d3.stack().keys([0,1,2,3]);
stack.value(function (d, key) {
      return d[key].y;
});
var layers = stack(d3.transpose(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m, .1); }))),
```

Then it's a simple matter of modifying the names according to the new syntax.

I updated your fiddle so that it works for v4.

see:
https://jsfiddle.net/9y2g65qc/20/