# d3.js stack layout upgrading from v3 to v4

Tags: d3.js

Using D3 v3, I formatted my data to match Mike's example to quick start my dev process. Example page here https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Stack-Layout.md

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "apples",
    "values": [
      { "x": 0, "y":  91},
      { "x": 1, "y": 290}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "oranges",
    "values": [
      { "x": 0, "y":  9},
      { "x": 1, "y": 49}
    ]
  }
];
```

Then all i had to do to obtain the stacked values was

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack().values(d=>d.values)

var layers = stack(data)
```

Exactly how he did it in his example.

However, in v4 it seems like the stack function expects tabular formatted data, so the above data would look like this.

```
var data = [
  {x: 0, apples: 91, oranges: 9},
  {x: 1, apples: 290, oranges: 49},
];
```

Is there an easy way to keep my data format and use the v4 stack function? I can't seem to grok the new way to do this. In my current data format, i have useful properties associated with the values array. If i change my data format to tabular, I don't see a convenient way to pair properties with values.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. Unfortunately, the new way doesn't seem to match the way APIs serialize model instances (sort of like your original data); instead you're stuck with JSONified tabular data format. I feel like this works when you're working with csv dumps, but that's not generally how databases are organised.

I've posted a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006527/3790954) that transforms object-grouped format (eg by fruit in your example) into data-point format (by x-coordinate in your example) as expected by `d3.stack()`. You'll be able to adapt the code to your particular case.