# Stack a matrix in d3 without remapping to json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

[The docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stacks) for d3's stacking function `d3.stack` show an example with an array of objects (each json object representing the ensemble of points for whatever the x-axis is measuring). Eg:

```
var data = [
  {month: new Date(2015, 0, 1), apples: 3840, bananas: 1920, cherries: 960},
  {month: new Date(2015, 1, 1), apples: 1600, bananas: 1440, cherries: 720}
]
```

I'm trying to produce a stacked histogram with a matrix of data series (`[ [], [], [], etc ]`). It's easy enough to iterate through the rows and get a series of histogram bins (having pre-defined the x scale and domain elsewhere):

```
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    bins[i] = d3.histogram()
            .domain(x.domain())
            .thresholds(x.ticks(10))
            (data[i]);
    }
```

And create groups for each data series inside another loop:

```
let bars = this.svg.selectAll(".series" + i)
    .data(this.bins[i])
    .enter().append("g")
    .classed("series" + i, true)
```

But of course doing it like that I get stuck here. How am I supposed to `bars.append("rect")` at the correct x,y coords for that particular series? Stated differently, I have a really useful array of `bins` at the moment, looking something like:

```
[
  [[1,2,3,3], [5,8,9], [10], ... etc], //series0 grouping by bins of 5
  [[1,3], [7,7,9,9], [11], ... etc], //series1
  [[2,3,3], [8,9], [10,12], ... etc], //series2
  ...etc
]
```

Is there a way to invoke `stack` without munging all the data into json key,value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a glance at [the source](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/stack.js) and no comments + single char variables = me understanding that it's not going to happen without munging. I present therefore my shoddy attempt at saving someone else some time:

```
/*
 * Static helper method to transform an array of histogram bins into an array of objects
 * suitable for feeding into the d3.stack() function.
 * Args:
 *  bins (array): an array of d3 histogram bins
 */
static processBins(bins){
    let temp = {}; // the keys for temp will be the bin name (i.e. the bin delimiter value)
    // now create an object with a key for each bin, and an empty object as a placeholder for the data
    bins[0].map( (bin) => { temp[bin.x0] = {}});
    for(let i=0; i<bins.length; i++){
        //traverse each series
        bins[i].map( bin => { 
            temp[bin.x0]["series"+i] = bin.length; //push the frequency counts for each series
        });
    }
    /* now we have an object whose top-level keys are the bins:
    { 
        binName0: { series0: freqCount0, series1: freqCount1, ...},
        binName1: {...},
        ...
    }
    now, finally we're going to make an arrays of objects containing all the series' freqencies for that bin
    */
    let result = [];
    for(let binName in temp){                       // iterate through the bin objects
        let resultRow = {};
        if(temp.hasOwnProperty(binName)){
            resultRow["bin"] = binName;             //put the bin name key/value pair into the result row
            for(let seriesName in temp[binName]){   //iterate through the series keys
                if(temp[binName].hasOwnProperty([seriesName])){
                    resultRow[seriesName] = temp[binName][seriesName];
                }
            }
        }
        result.push(resultRow);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call like:

```
let stack = d3.stack().keys( bins.map( (d,i)=>{return "series"+i})); //stack based on series name keys
let layers = stack(MyCoolHistogram.processBins(bins));
//and now your layers are ready to enter() into a d3 selection.
```

Edit:
I note that the stack data third argument in anonymous functions seems to be the array of elements. I.e. it's no longer the stack layer index. Eg, when grouping bars side-by-side: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967

This breaks grouping functions that rely on this index number to calculate the x position:

```
rect.attr("x", (d,i,j) => { return x(d.data.bin) + j*barWidth/numberOfSeries});
```

I guess it's telling that Mike's gist still uses v3, despite being updated long after v4 came out.

To get the layer index you have to use the `layer.index` attribute directly. So when grouping you would translate the entire layer (which screws up bar-by-bar animations, of course... sigh).

```
let layers = d3.stack(yourData);
let layer = this.svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
layer.transition()
    .attr("transform", d => { return "translate(" + d.index*barWidth/numberOfSeries + ",0)"; });
```