# Issues in converting StackBar chart from D3.js version 3 to version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to convert d3v3 Stacked bar chart with tooltips  (http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713) into d3v4. After many attempts still unable to get the chart running in d3v4.
Currently I have issue in changing below d3v3 code snippet to d4v3 code. Can anyone help me on this.

```
// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
        return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
    });
}));
```

Below are part of the links refereed for this task.
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md, https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/93, [{d3.js} migration v3 to v4: code work on v3 (d3.layout.stack()) error v4 (d3.stack())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120615/d3-js-migration-v3-to-v4-code-work-on-v3-d3-layout-stack-error-v4-d3-sta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally base any chart of Mike Bostock when you're making new charts if you're not familiar with d3.

I based it of [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) example

And here's my result taking the data from your example (I assumed you want your data to be hardcoded) Including the tooltip as well.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5i5evoQtookJLJXflvt?p=preview)**

Only real change I had to make was this:

```
.text(d[1] - d[0]);
```

In the tooltip `mousemove` event, take a look through the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) as well for further version conversion in the future.